# Single page Template for pages that begin with 'confirmation-'

Tags: page-template

I am trying to set a single page template that will apply to any page which URL begins with confirmation-.

For example (page names):

```
confirmation-tt5,
confirmation-556,
```

Should I just create a `single-confirmation` or will I need a custom filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of the `page_template` filter to achieve this. All we need to do is to make sure that `confirmation` is the first word in the page page title

```
add_filter( 'page_template', function ( $template )
{
    // Get the current page object
    $post = get_queried_object();

    /**
     * Get the first instance of confirmation, if it is not 0, bail
     * We will be using the page name, which is the slug
     */
    if ( 0 !== stripos( $post->post_name, 'confirmation' ) )
        return $template;

    // We have confimation as first word, lets continue
    $locate_template = locate_template( 'page-confirmation.php' );

    // Check if $locate_template is not empty, if so, bail
    if ( !$locate_template )
        return $template;

    // page-confirmation.php exist, return it
    return $locate_template;
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much Pieter, you are fast becoming my own personal WP Jedi :)

Comment: Ah, this code is overriding all other page templates..

Comment: We just needed a stricter check, `!==` works, check updated code

Comment: Glad it worked. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url,'confirmation') == true) {

    include(locate_template('page-confirmation.php'));

}
```

I managed to come up with this solution, not very elegant though as this code needs to be put into default `page.php`, I would prefer a filter of some sort that does this dynamically.